# Find $n$ in $n \log_2 n = c$

Tags: logarithms

I'm trying to find the value for $n$ in the following equation.

$$n \log_2 n = c$$

what is $n$?

thanks,
Tim

Comment: Is $c$ an integer? a real number? a complex number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no closed solution formula for such equations. You will have to find the solution numerically -- that is, by trial and error, bisection, Newton iteration or the like.

(One *can* write down a solution in terms of the [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), but from a practical point of view that "solution" just amounts to giving a fancy name to our inability to get an exact solution using ordinary algebra. It doesn't actually help with calculating the solution).

Comment: Thanks, I can get an answer with trial and error, so I'll just have do to that.

Answer (score 0):

$n = 2^k \implies k 2^k = c \implies (k \log2)  e^{k \log (2)} = c \log 2$. Now the [Lambert function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), $W(z)$, is defined as $$W(z) e^{W(z)} = z$$ Hence, $$k \log 2 = W(c \log 2) \implies k = \dfrac{W(c \log 2)}{\log 2} \implies n = 2^{\dfrac{W(c \log 2)}{\log 2}} = \exp \left( W(c \log 2)\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

Such equations have the following solution :
$$n = \frac{c\ln(2)}{W(c\ln(2))}$$
where $W$ is the Lambert-W function.